Transformation of random variables to get a sample for another probability density function
Question:
Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a two dimensional unit disk, given by $\mathcal{D}=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$. Using rejection sampling algorithm, I managed to generate a two dimensional random vector $(X,Y)$ from $\mathcal{D}$. Now,let
$f(x,y)$ be a probability density function proportional to $$\exp\{-x^2-y^2\}I\{|x|+|y|\leq 1\}$$
where $I\{.\}$ is the indicator function. Assume $(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}) \sim f(x,y)$. Let $(X_i,Y_i), i= 1,\cdots,n,$ be independent and identically distributed random vectors generated from the rejection sampling mentioned above. Use $(X_i,Y_i), i=1,\cdots,n$ to construct an unbiased estimator for $E(\tilde{X}^2,\tilde{Y}^2)$.
My attempt:
I am trying to find the map between $(X,Y)$ and $(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$ so sampling from $(X,Y)$ is is equivalent to sampling from $(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$. However, I couldn't find this mapping, are there any tips to solve this?
